# Slick Carousel integration is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have looked through the other answers regarding the Slik Carousel and I cant seem to resolve my issue. As advised in other answers I have attempted to use the CDN hosted js and css files in my  and   But It still did not work. I followed the instructions on http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/  to the best of my ability but I am not getting it to work quite right. I am really not so great at Javascript so any input from your guys and gals is greatly appreciated. Here is my code right now.

```
 <div class="featured-areas responsive">
 <div><a href="/lake-oswego-or-homes-for-sale"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/lakeoswegojpg.jpg"/></a><a href="/lake-oswego-or-homes-for-sale"><h3 style="text-align:center;">Lake Oswego Homes for Sale</h3></a></div>
  <div><a href="/lake-oswego-or-homes-for-sale"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/lakeoswegojpg.jpg"/></a><a href="/lake-oswego-or-homes-for-sale"><h3 style="text-align:center;">Lake Oswego Homes for Sale</h3></a></div>
  <div><a href="/lake-oswego-or-homes-for-sale"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/lakeoswegojpg.jpg"/></a><a href="/lake-oswego-or-homes-for-sale"><h3 style="text-align:center;">Lake Oswego Homes for Sale</h3></a></div>
  <div><a href="/lake-oswego-or-homes-for-sale"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/lakeoswegojpg.jpg"/></a><a href="/lake-oswego-or-homes-for-sale"><h3 style="text-align:center;">Lake Oswego Homes for Sale</h3></a></div>
  <div><a href="/lake-oswego-or-homes-for-sale"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/lakeoswegojpg.jpg"/></a><a href="/lake-oswego-or-homes-for-sale"><h3 style="text-align:center;">Lake Oswego Homes for Sale</h3></a></div>
  <div><a href="/lake-oswego-or-homes-for-sale"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/lakeoswegojpg.jpg"/></a><a href="/lake-oswego-or-homes-for-sale"><h3 style="text-align:center;">Lake Oswego Homes for Sale</h3></a></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">$('.responsive').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
    // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
    // settings: "unslick"
    // instead of a settings object
  ]
});
</script>
```

The site can be viewed on a test url as the nameservers are not pointed yet. I appreciate this help as it is going to be an excellent education for me to be able to bring to my clients.

it appears that the temp link is not working and the site used to generate the links is not working either. To view the site add the line to the hosts file: 108.178.13.98 findlakeoswegohomes.com

in the wp-head.php file:

```
   <?php

// =============================================================================
// VIEWS/INTEGRITY/WP-HEADER.PHP
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Header output for Integrity.
// =============================================================================

?>

<?php x_get_view( 'global', '_header' ); ?>

  <?php x_get_view( 'global', '_slider-above' ); ?>

  <header class="<?php x_masthead_class(); ?>" role="banner">
    <?php x_get_view( 'global', '_topbar' ); ?>
    <?php x_get_view( 'global', '_navbar' ); ?>
    <?php x_get_view( 'integrity', '_breadcrumbs' ); ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.4.1/slick.css"/>
  </header>

  <?php x_get_view( 'global', '_slider-below' ); ?>
  <?php x_get_view( 'integrity', '_landmark-header' ); ?>
```

then in the footer.php file:

```
<?php

// =============================================================================
// VIEWS/GLOBAL/_FOOTER.PHP
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Includes the wp_footer() hook and closes out the <body> and <html> tags.
// =============================================================================

?>

  <?php do_action( 'x_before_site_end' ); ?>

  </div> <!-- END #top.site -->

  <?php do_action( 'x_after_site_end' ); ?>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.4.1/slick.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I did actually load the css and the js files into a folder on the server called "slick"  and linked the stylesheet and js that way but it didnt work so I thought I would try the CDN version of the files to check to see if that was the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code is not wrapped inside a document ready, try putting your javascript code inside this:

```
$(function(){
    // Your Code Here
});
```

Make sure you are including the jQuery library before your `<script>` above.
Also make sure you are including the actual Slick Carousel javascript file (after jQuery library).

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by this. I checked and it looks like the script calling the slick file is loading right before the closing of the <body> tag.

Comment: There are other jquery scripts running. I am not sure how to check when the jquery library is being loaded

Comment: You are either linking to the jQuery library via a CDN, such as being hosted on Google, or you have downloaded jQuery and you are linking to that file. Try console.log($) at the end of your script (inside the script tags). It would help to see ALL of your code. You could paste it on Pastebin.

Comment: how do i actually view the output of the log?

Comment: I can give the login to the cms to view everything or send out files for viewing. It is a theme framework that we use to make sites for clients. there is a wp-head.php file and there is a footer.php file.

The wp-head contains the <head> tag. In here is where I placed the link for the stylesheet like this :<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.4.1/slick.css"/>  right before the closing of the header tag:

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome to open Developer Tools. Click the Console tab. Do you have any errors? Such as `$ is undefined`? In your code sample it looks like you haven't included jQuery. Try adding `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` just before your Slick script file in the footer.

Comment: something happened when i added that script you sent. it said unexpected > token

Comment: ok well my slider revolution plugin said that to find the double jquery.js include and remove it so it appears to be loaded somewhere. I know there are a few things that use jquery already on the site so it must be loaded at some point before the slider revolution plugin.

Comment: i get this from the console Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function(anonymous function) @ (index):375
(index):625 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: the unexpected token is from another plugin's output. I am unable to actually get into the plugin to try to fix it. it just comes as is from the provider

Comment: <script type='text/javascript' src='http://findlakeoswegohomes.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.3'></script>

that is in the header so I am assuming that the framework we are using is loading the jquery library in the very beginning of the loading of the page